# Do something at variable change in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jframe, listener

I want to do the following: As soon as a specific Variable (roomName) changes its Value, the Title of a JFrame should be changed to the new Value of roomName.
My only problem is, that the JFrame is already built before the roomName changes.

This is a little snippet of my Connection.java Class:

```
public Connection() {
    ...
    fieldName.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            if(e.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
                setName();
            }
        }
    });
}

public void setName(){
    ChatFrame.frame.setVisible(true);
    ChatFrame.roomName = fieldName.getText();
    this.dispose();
}
```

The other Class ChatFrame.java should do the described Action above.
Do I need a Listener or a Thread for this? What's the best way to do it?

Comment: Give us more info (maybe ChatFrame class) please.

Comment: @AlicanOzgoren The ChatFrame class isn't very important. It's really just a JFrame which just shows a little Chat Application. It's not relevant for my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One simple solution that springs to mind is to wrap the variable up into an object, then the setter method can look like this:

```
public void setNewValue(String newVal)
{
    if(!newVal.equals(currentVal)) {
        currentVal = newVal;
        // Value has changed. Call the relevant code.
    }
}
```

Comment: and how does this solve the problem of not updateing the ´JFrame`?

Comment: Well "call the relevant code" could be update the value in the `JFrame` with the new value. I'm not doing everything for them.

Comment: That's actually a good idea, but I'd have to make the method static, which would make the call of setTitle() impossible.

Answer (score 2):

You should make the `ChatFrame` variable private to start with, exposing a *method* to change it:

```
public void setRoomName(String newName) {
    ...
}
```

Then you can add a listener for that, and trigger it within the method.

Note that this should logically be an *instance* variable, not a *static* variable as it appears to be at the moment.

(If that's not what you were looking for, please edit your question. It's very unclear at the moment, partly as we're not sure where the `setName` method is, or whether you've *really* got static variables for `roomName` and `frame`.)